# Trying to get property 'insert_id' of non-object

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este codigo que permite crear un usuario, guarda los datos en ambas tablas junto con todos sus datos. Hasta ahí anda bien.
El problema es que en ambas tablas deberia guardar la misma ID del usuario. Para despues identificar cual contraseña pertenece a cual usuario.

```
  function agregarUsuario ()
    {
        $link = conectar();
        $nomyape = $_POST ['nomyape'];
        $email = $_POST ['email'];
        $telefono = $_POST ['telefono'];
        $id_categoria = $_POST ['id_categoria'];
        $activo = $_POST ['activo'];
        $password = $_POST ['password'];
        $id_escuela = $_POST ['id_escuela'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios ( nomyape, email, telefono, id_categoria, activo ) VALUES ( '".$nomyape."', '".$email."', '".$telefono."', '".$id_categoria."', 1 )";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql)  or die( mysqli_error($link) );
        $ultimoID = $sql->insert_id;
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO usuarioesc (id_usuario, id_escuela, password ) VALUES ( '".$ultimoID."', '".$id_escuela."', '".$password."')";
        $resultado2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2) or die( mysqli_error($link) );
        return [$resultado, $resultado2];
    }
```

Hay 2 tablas:

usuarios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

usuarioesc
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no se está guardando la id del usuario en la tabla de usuarioesc. Lo que necesito lograr es que el dato que se ingresa en la tabla usuarioesc, es el ID de la tabla usuarios que se acaba de crear en la 1ª consulta.

Con este código tengo este error:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'insert_id' of non-object in
> C:...\usuarios.php on line 28 Incorrect
> integer value: '' for column `escuela`.`usuarioesc`.`id_usuario`
> at row 1

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115616/discussion-on-question-by-cloby-guardar-id-del-usuario-en-2-tablas).

Comment: Por favor @A.Cedano, escribi una respuesta entonces.

Comment: Actualice el cógido y las imágenes de las tablas. Revise si me faltaba algun ; o ". Ahora me salta `Notice: Trying to get property 'insert_id' of non-object in C:\...\usuarios.php on line 28
Incorrect integer value: '' for column `escuela`.`usuarioesc`.`id_usuario` at row 1`

Comment: Los errores deben ir en la pregunta. SI editas a cada rato, no se puede escribir una respuesta.

Comment: Ok, solo puse el error en la pregunta. Ya no lo edito mas